# PHP: pass a variable to a function, do something to the variable, return it back

Tags: php, variables, return

Assuming the following code:

```
<?php
function doStuff($rowCount) {
    $rowCount++;
    echo $rowCount.' and ';
    return $rowCount;
}
$rowCount = 1;
echo $rowCount.' and ';
doStuff($rowCount);
doStuff($rowCount);
doStuff($rowCount);
?>
```

The desired output is

```
1 and 2 and 3 and 4 and
```

The actual output is

```
1 and 2 and 2 and 2 and
```

I take it I'm musunderstanding how "return" works in this context. How could I best accomplish this?

Comment: i guess you need to review your understanding of variable scope, pass by value and reference concepts in php...

Answer (score 10):

You either have to assign the return value of the `doStuff` calls back to the local `$rowCount` variable:

```
$rowCount = 1;
echo $rowCount.' and ';
$rowCount = doStuff($rowCount);
$rowCount = doStuff($rowCount);
$rowCount = doStuff($rowCount);
```

Or you pass the variable as a [reference](http://php.net/language.references) by putting a `&` in front of the formal parameter `$rowCount`:

```
function doStuff(&$rowCount) {
    $rowCount++;
    echo $rowCount.' and ';
    return $rowCount;
}
```

Now the formal parameter `$rowCount` inside the function `doStuff` refers to the same value as the variable that is passed to `doStuff` in the function call.

Answer (score 2):

You should try this :

```
$rowCount = 1;
echo $rowCount.' and ';
$rowCount = doStuff($rowCount);
$rowCount = doStuff($rowCount);
$rowCount = doStuff($rowCount);
```

Your `doStuff()` method returns an int that is never used when you simply use the statement `doStuff($rowCount);` without assignation.

Answer (score 1):

change `function doStuff($rowCount)`

to `function doStuff(&$rowCount)`

Normally in PHP you're sending a copy of the variable to the function, so modifications within the function will not affect the value of the variable outside of the function.  Adding the ampersand tells PHP to send a reference to the variable instead so modifications to the variable propagate back to the caller.

Comment: Why use this kind of method whereas doStuff already returns the new value of `$rowCount` ?

Comment: in your code, to what variable are you actually storing the returned value?

Comment: @ultrajohn - I'm not, the returned value gets dropped.

Comment: @Colin - I read too fast and didn't see the return value before I answered :)

Comment: oh, sorry, i thought @colin was the OP.. ;( 
@tloach, my question was actually address to Colin, whom i thought was the OP..

Answer (score 1):

i would just try to fix the code: ...

```
<?php
function doStuff($rowCount) {
    $rowCount++;
    echo $rowCount.' and ';
    return $rowCount;
}
$rowCount = 1;
echo $rowCount.' and ';
doStuff(doStuff(doStuff($rowCount)));

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the variable 'by reference' instead of 'by value' to accomplish this add an & to the variable in the function declaration:

```
function doStuff(&$rowCount);
```

Also check out [PHP: Passing by Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php)